# Oracle - Using to_date, how to convert varchar to today's date

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table where I store the times as varchars:

```
Times
starttime
00:00
16:00
22:00
```

From this table I can convert the column to a date like this:

```
Select to_date(starttime,'hh24:mi') from times
```

This gives me the following:

```
01/03/2013 00:00:00
01/03/2013 16:00:00
01/03/2013 22:00:00
```

How can I change this query so I can prefix the time values with today's date so I get the following instead: (16/03/2013 is today's date)

```
16/03/2013 00:00:00
16/03/2013 16:00:00
16/03/2013 22:00:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')||' '||starttime, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the difference between the current date and the start of the month. I prefer this to string operations as you stick with dates, but it doesn't make much difference.

You can use [TRUNC()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151) to work it out:

```
select to_date('09:00','hh24:mi') + ( trunc(sysdate) - trunc(sysdate, 'mm'))
  from dual
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8850)

`trunc(sysdate)` is the earliest today and `trunc(sysdate, 'mm')` is the beginning of the month. Oracle's date arithmetic means that it returns a day difference between today and the beginning of the month; giving you the difference you need to add to your original TO_DATE().